# Android Lint - How to exclude directory from checks

Tags: android, lint

The Android Lint generated Lint Report suggests the following `lint.xml` rule to exclude an entire path from Lint checks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <!-- Ignore everything in the test source set -->
    <issue id="all">
        <ignore path="*/test/*" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

However, with version `3.2.0` of the Android Gradle plugin (and the Lint version it references), the build fails with the following error:

```
Error: Unknown issue id "all", found in [..]/app/lint.xml [LintError]
```

It works fine with version `3.1.4` or lower. Is there a way to make it work with the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug introduced in version 3.2.0 (most probably with [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/32969ce85a9115c66101e0e382431becc78c6e52%5E%21/lint/cli/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/LintCliClient.java))

The only way to make it work again is to star the following issue on the Android bug tracker and wait until Google provides a fixed version:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116677290